# Django: NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset, distinct

I have a table called reviews. In the reviews a person can leave multiple reviews for a service. A review can have a total score. I am trying to get the average of the total scores for the distinct reviews. Here is what I have:

```
reviews = Review.objects.distinct('pairing').aggregate(Avg('total_score'));
```

I keep getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

Could someone help me? I am fairly new to Django and have no clue why I am getting this. Thanks!

Comment: Is `pairing` a `ForeignKey`? Can you share the related models?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [**`values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) and then create an `Avg`:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

reviews = Review.objects.values('pairing').aggregate(
    avg_total_score=Avg('total_score')
).order_by('pairing')
```

This will create a `QuerySet` of dictionaries that looks like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'pairing': 13, 'avg_total_score': 1.3},
    {'pairing': 14, 'avg_total_score': 2.7},
    {'pairing': 21, 'avg_total_score': 1.8},
    {'pairing': 25, 'avg_total_score': 3.9},
]>
```

Comment: Will this take the unique pairings for the queryset? For example, there may be 2 ratings with the same pairing, but I am trying to get just the first rating with a unique rating

Comment: @TotiCuervo: if the same `pairing` occurs multiple times, it will be once in the result, and the `avg_total_score` will be the average `total_score` for all the records with *that* `pairing`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! However what I am looking for is the average of that entire queries that. The objective of using the state is to only get the first rating with a specific pairing. For example if I have a queryset                                           
    {'pairing': 1, 'total_score': 1.3},
    {'pairing': 1, 'total_score': 2.7},
    {'pairing': 2, 'total_score': 1.8},
then it will only take the average total score of                                                                   
    {'pairing': 1, 'total_score': 2.7},
    {'pairing': 2, 'total_score': 1.8},

Comment: @TotiCuervo: if `pairing` is a `ForeignKey` however, it is more elegant to perform a `.annotate(..)` on the model it is pointing at, since then you have (given that model exists `Pairing` objects) with an extra attribute.

Comment: @TotiCuervo: but the problem is that there is no such thing as a "first". You should consider tables "unordered". There is just a de-facto ordering, but the database can return the records in any order it wants, unless you thus have an ordering condition.

Comment: @TotiCuervo: it is also not clear why your question contains an `Avg` given you are interested in some "first" record.